# LuaTeX cannot find existing font

Tags: fonts, errors, luatex, luaotfload

My Fedora 17 LuaLaTeX (2012) system just keeps complaining about some particular (of course existing) font not existing. It can't spit out any PDF from a TeX file using that font. This is the error I am getting:

> !LuaTeX error: cannot find OpenType font file for reading ()
>   ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

I am 100% positive the otf font file exists and that the path I am giving to setmainfont is correct.

After perusing TeX StackExchange searching for help, I couldn't find any recommendation that worked.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.sx. It's perfectly fine to ask a question and then answer it. This would be preferable to having an answer in the question.  So perhaps you can edit your question just showing the error you got originally and then add your own answer as an answer.  This way the question doesn't remain perpetually unanswered.

Comment: Where exactly is the font? And how exactly are you calling it with `setmainfont`?

Comment: Try `fclist | grep <fontname>` to see whether the font is installed or not.

Comment: Does running `mkluatexfontdb` help?

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot say, Martin. My problems are gone since I deleted the broken `.lua` files as I explained in my own answer. So trying `mkluatexfontdb` does nothing now (apart from a trivial information message).

Comment: It usually means the font path luaotfload is passing to the engine does not exist, and this usually happens when the files are moved but luaotfload didn't update its font database.

Comment: Khaled, if you mean the **font** files are moved, they weren't. What I think happened is this: some lua font cache job was interrupted and a corrupted lua font cache file was the result. Please see my own solution below.

Comment: @MartinSchröder I have the same problem. Clearing the cache does not work and `mkluatexfontdb` returns
`The program 'mkluatexfontdb' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install texlive-luatex`
even though attempting to install texlive-luatex returns the message that it is already installed.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I just found a solution.

It turned out it was all about cleaning my LuaTeX font cache.

Try that if you face the same problem. Go to your home folder. Activate viewing of hidden files (Ctrl+H). Look for `.texlive2012/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf` and delete the `.lua` file(s) that more closely match your "existing but not found" fontname.

That did the trick in my case, and forever. I suppose an interrupted PDF compilation was the culprit.

Comment: Bingo, this answer is a lifesaver. It's important to note that the font you need to delete might be the one just *after* the ones reported before the fatal error, i.e. it might not be reported in the LaTeX output.

Comment: This one helped for me as well - I had to delete the entire `otl` folder though (see also here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/416183/setmainfont-error-on-path-2-levels-deep)

Comment: On macOS the relevant path seems to be `~/Library/texlive/2021/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/`.

Comment: This saved me hours (after hours spent).