# How to debug LuaLaTeX no longer finding ttf font

Tags: luatex, fontspec

I just updated texlive and now LuaLateX no longer finds two `ttf` fonts situated in the same folder as the .tex file. Before I updated it all worked fine. Clumsy as I am I was having a `latexmk` session open in a terminal during the update and I am wondering if perhaps this could have broken some font cache, i.e. something similar to [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65038/luatex-cannot-find-existing-font)? But on the other hand I am unsure as to whether it is using the font cache for fonts in the local folder? I tried `mkluatexfontdb` but that shouldn't really have any effect on files in local folder should it?

Can someone suggest what to try next?

btw I am now running version: `beta-0.76.0-2013061817  (TeX Live 2013) (rev 4627)`

Comment: Have you recently updated `luaotfload` via `tlmgr`? If so, do `luaotfload-tool -u` from the terminal. But first ensure your TeX Live is fully updated (there was a bug in an update to `luaotfload` that was solved a few days later).

Comment: Tested. Made no difference though :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a hunch I tried removing the `.ttf` part in the specification and then it suddenly worked. Seems the `BoldItalicFont` and `BoldFont` in the `\setmainfont` command no longer is happy with getting the `.ttf` part of the file name. It probably makes sense but perhaps someone will find it useful knowledge some time... :)

Answer (score 2):

NB this is an answer to the original question. I described my experience with adding a new ttf font.

I use lualatex, first installed tex-live, on my new Ubuntu 14 lts, I want to use from XP font constantia. 
I copied all CONSTANT*.TTF-files from XP in this map: `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts` analogically(!) like other already available fonts.
NB you have to be root for this!

Of course in the preamble something like:

```
\documentclass[pdftex]{book} %

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage[dutch]{babel}

\usepackage{luacode,luatexbase}

\usepackage{fontspec}% "[Renderer=Basic,Ligatures=TeX]"% nodig voor "--" and "---"

\setmainfont[Renderer=Basic,Ligatures=TeX]{Constantia} % case dependant
```

Then it's necessary to make this font available (in Abiword you can check it out)
(you have probably to be root for some of these actions; "$" is terminal prompt)

```
$ fc-cache -fv 

$ mkluatexfontdb -vvv # per user and (idem):

$ luatools --configurations # luatex has to know where a new font is to be found.
```

All these steps were necessary. Greetz, Ernst van der Storm, The Netherlands

Comment: Please explain how your posting addresses the question that was posed. If it's not an answer, please consider re-posting it as a new question -- while making clear what the issues are that need to be addressed.