# lualatex: Error when loading a font from a relative path

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, paths

I'm trying to load a .ttf from lualatex, which works fine when I place the .ttf in the same folder as the .tex file. However, for my project structure it would be beneficial to store .ttf files in a parent directory and load the fonts from e.g. `../Fonts/myCustomFont.ttf`. From [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12568/30658) I have learned that I can use the `Path` argument for instance with `setmainfont`. My minimal example looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[Path = ../Fonts/]{agfarotissansserif.ttf}
% check: the required trailing slash is there

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

However, lualatex produces this fatal error with this example:

```
!LuaTeX error: cannot find OpenType font file for reading ()
```

I made the following observations:

- Placing the `agfarotissansserif.ttf` file in the same directory (and removing the `Path` argument) works fine.
- In order to check whether lualatex actually reads the .ttf I renamed it, so that I'm really loading from a non-existing path. In this case lualatex gives a "font not found" error. This means that the path argument seems to have an effect, and lualatex can find the file.
- It does not seem to be a font problem. I get the same behavior with other .ttf files as well.

Overall I'm confused: It looks like lualatex actually does find the .ttf, and that it is capable of loading the font in general. Any ideas why I'm getting a fatal error nevertheless?

For the record: I did try `ExternalLocation` instead of `Path` and it looks like it behaves exactly the same. It also does not matter whether the font folder is a parent or a subdirectory. [This trick](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65087/30658) of clearing the lua font cache did not help either.

My specs: Ubuntu 14.04 with Texlive 2013 from the Ubuntu repositories.

**Update:**

If I run `luaotfload-tool --find=../Fonts/agfarotissansserif.ttf` (from the subdirectory of the .tex, so that the path makes sense), I get:

```
luaotfload | resolve : Font "../Fonts/agfarotissansserif.ttf" found!
luaotfload | resolve : Resolved file name "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/padauk/Padauk-bold.ttf"
```

Another strange observation: I get the same output even if `../Fonts/agfarotissansserif.ttf` does **not** exist.

In contrast, if I run `luaotfload-tool --find=agfarotissansserif.ttf` in the same folder as the .ttf, I get:

```
luaotfload | resolve : Font "agfarotissansserif.ttf" found!
luaotfload | resolve : Resolved file name "./agfarotissansserif.ttf"
```

In this case, if the .ttf does not exist, I get `Cannot find "agfarotissansserif.ttf" in index` as expected.

Does this explain the problem?

Comment: For what it's worth I cannot seem to replicate this error. Your above code works for me on TeX Live 2015. Have you tried updating your distribution?

Comment: Are the fonts located `../Fonts` directory known to Lua(La)TeX? (You could run the `luaotfload-tool` to find out...) Which TeX distribution, and which operating system, do you have on your system?

Comment: From [this changelog](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/luatex/generic/luaotfload/NEWS) it seems there was a fix for path handling in v2.4 of `luaotfload-tool`, which was released 2013/12/31.

Comment: You can check your `luaotfload-tool` version by running `luaotfload-tool --version` on the command line.

Comment: @nordev: What confuses me: If loading from a relative path was really broken in Texlive 2013, then I would have expected at least a comment in the famous [_load fonts that are in a ./fonts directory_ question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12568/30658). I have `luaotfload-tool version "2.4-3"` and `luaotfload-tool --find=agfarotissansserif.ttf` returns not found, if that is what @Mico meant.

Comment: @bluenote10 Try `luaotfload-tool --find ../Fonts/agfarotissansserif.ttf`, if you are in the same directory as the `.tex` file, and the font is in the parent directory.

Comment: @nordev @Mico There is indeed a very strange difference when I resolve the font from the same or from a different directory -- see updated question. I have no idea why luaotfload suddenly resolves to this `Padauk-bold.ttf`.