# /setmainfont Error on path 2 levels deep?

Tags: fonts, luatex

I am trying to house all my customizations and fonts in an asset folder so I can use it on multiple documents and maintain the same styles. Unfortunately whenever I try and put the fonts into a path two levels deep I can't compile the document. I get the error:

```
! error:  (type 2): cannot find file ''
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Below works:

```
\newcommand{\fontmercury}{\setmainfont[Path = ./fonts/,
  BoldFont=mercurybd.ttf,
  ItalicFont=mercuryi.ttf,
  BoldItalicFont=mercurybi.ttf
  ]{mercury.ttf}
}
```

This does not work:

```
\newcommand{\fontmercury}{\setmainfont[Path = ./assets/fonts/,
  BoldFont=mercurybd.ttf,
  ItalicFont=mercuryi.ttf,
  BoldItalicFont=mercurybi.ttf
  ]{mercury.ttf}
}
```

The path is correct, it just generates an error anytime I go more than one level deep.

EDIT: I figured it out. It was the cache problem discussed here. Deleting the otl folder in my case allowed it to compile. [LuaTeX cannot find existing font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65038/luatex-cannot-find-existing-font)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure I would post this as an answer since I am not sure how to mark this as answered. But I figured it out shortly after posting. I use TeXLive + TeXWorks. So I deleted the otl folder in the path `C:\texlive\2017\texmf-var\luatex-cache\generic\fonts\otl`. It worked when it came to building the doc after.

More details: [LuaTeX cannot find existing font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65038/luatex-cannot-find-existing-font)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to deleting the out-of-date `otl` directory, you should also consider using a different setup for `\fontmercury`. The `fontspec` package provides the `\newfontfamily` directive. For the case at hand, using `\newfontfamily` would seem more efficient than issuing a `\setmainfont` directive. You could insert the following instructions in the preamble:

```
\newfontfamily{\mercury}{mercury.ttf}%
      [Path           = ./fonts/,
       BoldFont       = mercurybd.ttf,
       ItalicFont     = mercuryi.ttf,
       BoldItalicFont = mercurybi.ttf]
\newcommand{\fontmercury}[1]{{\mercury #1}}
```

Then, in the body of the document, you'd write

```
\fontmercury{...}
```